# Fine tuning Windows 7 indexing

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to fine tune indexing to do things like:

- don't index hidden files/directories
- don't index sub-dirs/files of a certain pattern, e.g always ignore folders named "_svn"

I would rather not turn indexing off on a whole directory, but I need to disable it on temporary files used by a certain application.

Comment: Some fine tuning can be done, , see this...http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Exploring-Windows-7s-New-Search-Features-Part2.html

Comment: @Moab do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think you can tweak things quite as much as you would like, there are some tweaks that can be made on a file-type and path basis. Here's a couple of Win Vista/Win 7 articles from HelpDeskGeek:

1. http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-vista-tips/add-folders-to-search-index-windows-vista/
2. http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-file-search-indexing-options/